# Getting frequently 403 Error on Apache centos6

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos6

I'm getting following error message frequently. If I hit refresh(F5) again, I get website without any issue.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /admin/product_scientist/index.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Server at www.mywebsite.com Port 80
```

I can't find any error message on access or error log. Not only mentioned page, getting error on most of the page even html. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration?

Comment: @ShaneMadden we are using plesk panel for website. can you pls tell which conf i need to provide ?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I found that, file and folder have permission with mysite( plesk user):root owner ship and 755 permission. Is it make any cause ???

Comment: do you have mod_evasive enabled?

Comment: @thatguyfromoverthere how can i check it ?

Comment: @Kumar: if you have console-access: `apachectl -M` or `apache2ctl -M`; if not, look for something like "modules". otherwise, phpinfo() maybe?

Answer (score -1):

For debian you could do as root:

```
# grep -ir "mod_evasive" /etc/apache2/
```

or for CentOS you could do:

```
# grep -ir "mod_evasive" /etc/httpd/
```

Or the slowest but 100% working grep on all distributions is:

```
# grep -ir "mod_evasive" /
```

And let's see what it returns.

Comment: no, apachectl is the way to go. you'll get (@ debina) also hits from mods-available and other opccurences, but not the list of actual loaded modules